# Image, upto direct summands, of derived push-forward of resolution of singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, triangulated-categories, resolution-of-singularities, derived-functors

Let $\mathcal C$ be a full subcategory (closed under isomorphism also) of an additive category $\mathcal A$. Then, $\text{add}(\mathcal C)$ is the full subcategory of $\mathcal A$ consisting of all objects that are direct summands of finite direct sums of copies of objects from $\mathcal C$. Let $X$ be a variety. Let $f: Y \to X$ and $g : Y'\to X$ be two resolution of singularities.  Then, there exists a smooth variety $Y''$ and birational morphisms $f': Y''\to Y$ and $g': Y''\to Y'$ such that $f\circ f'=g\circ g'$ .

Consider the derived push-forward $Rf_*: D(\text{QCoh } Y)\to D(\text{QCoh } X)$ and $R(f\circ f')_*: D(\text{QCoh } Y'')\to D(\text{QCoh } X)$.

Do the following equalities hold true:

(1) $\text{add}(Rf_* F : F \in D(\text{QCoh } Y))=\text{add}(R(f\circ f')_* G : G \in D(\text{QCoh } Y''))$ ?

(2) $\text{add}(Rf_* F : F \in D(\text{Coh } Y))=\text{add}(R(f\circ f')_* G : G \in D(\text{Coh } Y''))$ ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, both are true, because by the projection formula $Rg_*$ is essentially surjective on the derived categories.

Comment: There is something I am confused about here ... since $f$ is proper, every direct summand of $Rf_* F$ is in $D(\text{Coh} Y)$  for $F\in D(\text{Coh} Y)$ ... but do we know the same for $R(f\circ g)_* G$ when  $G\in D(\text{Coh} Y'')$ ?

Comment: For any $F$ there is $G$ such that $Rf'_*G \cong F$, hence $R(f \circ f')_*G \cong Rf_*F$.

Comment: I get that, but when $F$ is Coherent, can you also choose $G$ to be Coherent? That's the only difference between my questions (2) and (1) ...

Comment: there is another point also ... if $G\in \text{Coh } Y''$, then is $Rf'_* G$  in $D(\text{Coh } Y)$? Otherwise it is not possible to say that the essential image of $R(f\circ f')_*$ restricted to $D(\text{Coh } Y'')$ is contained in the essential image of $Rf_*$ restricted to $D(\text{Coh } Y)$ ....

Comment: Yes, you can take $G = L{f'}^*F$.

Comment: I am a little concerned about your application of projection formula ... don't you need the complexes to be bounded?

Comment: No, it is also true for unbounded complexes. Indeed, consider the subcategory of objects for which the natural morphism $F \to Rf'_*L{f'}^*F$ is an isomorphism. It is triangulated, contains all bounded complexes, and closed under arbitrary direct sums (because both functors commute with arbitrary direct sums), hence it contains all unbounded complexes.